# api resource returns 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

these are my api:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['as' => 'admin',
                     'middleware' => 'api.auth',
                     'namespace' => 'Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'admin/org_units', 'as' => 'org_units'], function ($api) {

            $api->get('/datatable', 'OrgUnitController@datatable')->name('.datatable');

            $api->resource('/', 'OrgUnitController');
    });

});
```

but `api/v1/admin/org_units/datatable` works find but `api/v1/admin/org_units/3` returns `404 Not Found` message.

my routes list:

```
|      | GET|HEAD                       | /api/v1/admin/org_units/datatable                                                                   | admin.org_units.datatable                                                               | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@datatable                                                       | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
|      | GET|HEAD                       | /api/v1/admin/org_units                                                                             | admin.org_units.index                                                                   | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@index                                                           | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
|      | POST                           | /api/v1/admin/org_units                                                                             | admin.org_units.store                                                                   | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@store                                                           | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
|      | GET|HEAD                       | /api/v1/admin/org_units/{}                                                                          | admin.org_units.show                                                                    | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@show                                                            | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
|      | PUT|PATCH                      | /api/v1/admin/org_units/{}                                                                          | admin.org_units.update                                                                  | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@update                                                          | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
|      | DELETE                         | /api/v1/admin/org_units/{}                                                                          | admin.org_units.destroy                                                                 | Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController@destroy                                                         | Yes       | v1         |          |            |
```

I think the end of my route list should be a `org_unit` parameters but the result is empty ( `{}` ) !

Answer (score 1):

Pass the missing parameter when creating the route

```php
$api->resource('/{org_unit}', 'Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController');
```

Make sure to have a route key name in your `OrgUnit` model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
   return 'id';
}
```

From [the docs](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Creating-API-Endpoints#creating-endpoints)

You can also register resources and controllers using the respective methods.

> Note that you must specify the full namespace to the controller, e.g., App\Http\Controllers.

You can also pass parameters like so [See This](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/1605)

```
$api->resource('org_units', 'Modules\OrgUnit\Http\Controllers\OrgUnitController', [
       'parameters' => ['org_unit' => 'application'],
])->middlware('bindings');
```

Comment: Not solved, I think this is a bug of `Dingo` library. Unfortunately I write two group: `admin` then inside of it `org_units`.